# "Damaged SD card" error on internal storage

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sd-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 Skyrocket and after rebooting my phone yesterday, it's now giving me a "Damaged SD card" on /storage/sdcard0. Here's the thing... I've never had an SD card, and there's no SD card in the phone. Yet all my data (pictures etc) and my camera are not working, saying there's no storage device available.

Any thoughts? How do I mark this as clean? I tried to "cd" into it on the terminal and got permission denied.

The device is rooted.

Comment: `/storage/sdcard0` is pointing to the internal SD card. If this one is broken for some reason you probably need to reformat it. Sometimes it's enough to just fix the partition headers (and leave the file tables intact) but often the partition is completely broken and you need to wipe it. Were any apps accessing the storage right before you rebooted?

Comment: @GiantTree Internal SD card, as in something I cannot physically access? That's weird. Any tips on something I can try before I do a full reformat (my pictures were on that)?

Comment: You could back it up (if your device is rooted or adb in recovery works) and have at least an image of the broken partition. Then you *could* try to fix the file system headers, but I'm not professional enough to give you all the commands for that.

Comment: Internal sd card like in emulated (virtual) card from a partition of the internal flash storage. Backup all data that's on it and try to erase it from settings -> storage (make sure you don't erase the wrong one)